# Add Compose context to pyplot axis or figure in julia

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I have two different visualizations: a big plot (as PyPlot figure) and a worldmap (Compose context). Is there any possibility to combine those? (out of julia, without exporting both and then fiddling with some software). 
I would like to do something like:

```
import PyPlot
using Compose

(fig, ax) = PyPlot.subplots(2,1)
ax[1][:plot]([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
composition = compose(compose(context(), circle()), fill("tomato"))

### magic command to add composition to ax[2]
```

In case there is no way to do it like this I will be greatefull for any other suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a Shapefile recipe for [Plots](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/PlotRecipes.jl). So in theory, at least, you can handle shapefiles and plots in the same package. However, since you're currently using PyPlot and Compose, this won't immediately solve your problem...

Comment: You can combine Gadfly plots with Compose contexts.

Comment: I guess the key question here is - why is your worldmap a compose context? And does your plot needs to be a Pyplot plot? As @daycaster said above, combining a plot with a shapefile is super easy in Plots.

Comment: @Michael The answer is - code recycling. Both things are big and elaborated so I wanted to awoid rewriting the code if possible. Further I'd like to keep it PyPlot compatible since it is a joint project where the half of the plots (I mean not amount-wise but subplot-wise) comes from someone who codes Python and PyPlot gives me a handy way to include the plots right from his code. So at the moment PyPlot Basemap seems appealing. But thanks for the input!

Comment: Yes, sounds like a good solution.